# Publish profile for .NET Core 5 is not showing up in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 5 application, I'm trying to create a web application in Azure. I'm not able to see the publish here with version .NET Core 5.

Please see this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's most likely because .NET 5 is no longer supported .... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @marc_s for the comment.

In `Visual Studio`, you can see that it clearly says, `.NET 5.0` is `Out of support`.

[image]

If you have developed the application in `.NET 5` and still want to deploy the App, you can continue it.

[image]

When you deploy the Application, runtime stack is taken as `.NET 5` , And it suggests you to update the version.

***When deployed from Visual Studio:***

[image]

You can see the `.NET 5` option now.

[image]

Whereas if you are creating the `App Service` from the  Azure portal    , you cannot see the option of  `.Net 5` (like you are seeing now in your case).

***From Azure App Service in Azure Portal:***

[image]